# Android Robotium: how to go back to my Activity under test after clicking/launching another Activity

Tags: android, unit-testing, android-activity, robotium

I have an issue with my Robotium tests. On one of my Activity A, I am clicking on a button. Clicking on this button launches another activity B. So in my robotium test I have something like this :

```
Button myBtn = (Button) solo.getView(R.id.myBtn);
```

so after this action, the emulator is automatically launching activity B. Now, the problem is that I do not have any possibility of going back to the activity under test (A) in the code.

Can you please tell me how to avoid getting jailed in the activity B when clicking on the button that trigger its launch ? In other words, is it possible to go back to the activity under test ?

**FYI** : I need to go back to the activity under test because there are other test methods waiting to be fired.

thanks in advance,

Answer (score 3):

Please try methods like

```
solo.clickOnView(R.id.myBtn)
```

to click on your button
You can also try

```
solo.clickOnButton()
```

To go back to activity you can use

```
solo.goBack();
```

or

```
solo.goBackToActivity("ActivityName");
```

Comment: Doesn't work for an activity which is not under test, for instance if there is a button which opens a browser non of the following methods return to the previous activity

Answer (score 2):

Once you call any activity outside your application, it’s not possible to come back to your application using `solo.<any API>`, because `solo` is tight to UID of your application and doesn't work on other app's activity (with different UID).

Basically `solo` can only work on activities which belong to the application for which it’s created.