# Android Instrumentation - How to detect external activity call

Tags: android, robotium, instrumentation

I am using Robotium for testing android applications and am interested in how to detect a situation when an external application activity (e.g. browser, camera, facebook) is being launched by tested app. There are [several](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9696449/how-to-handle-external-application-activity-in-android-using-robotium) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10653576/android-robotium-how-to-go-back-to-my-activity-under-test-after-clicking-launch) asking how to **handle** such situation, but all I need is to **detect** it, for example just log time when it's occurred. Is this possible using Robotium or simple Instrumentation?

BTW, I can't use the solution when system apps are being replaced by fake analogues, I can't even know what application (and when) will be launched, because the tests are random. (Yes, I know, it's a bad approach, but this is a project restriction).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3290936/android-detect-when-other-apps-are-launched/22303460#22303460). The main idea is to detect current top `Activity`, which is `Activity` of external application. You can create `Service`, which will monitor top activities.

Comment: Thanks, your solution seems acceptable. I think there may be some possibility to do this using Instrumentation advantages, so I'll give your answer a day or two before accept it.

Comment: If you find same functionality in Instrumentation advantages - it will very useful. mutual assistance ;)

Answer (score 0):

Anther way is to check when your activity looses focus. When it looses focus that means that the other external Activity has focus instead.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#hasWindowFocus()

You can use Solo.waitForCondition() in conjunction with hasWindowFocus.

Comment: But the activity loses focus even when the new activity of the same application appears.