# Robotium test Share Link an return to app for testing

Tags: android, robotium

I am doing testing for android app, My question is on button click i have  to open website in browser through robotium once the website is open i have to call solo.goback() or any appropriate  method so control comes back to the testing and testing proceeds further.

Can anybody tell me is there some way to do this.

Comment: I think it is better to use Espresso-Intents - http://wiebe-elsinga.com/blog/whats-new-in-android-testing/ The way you describe sounds wrong

Comment: How to  know whether the valid website was launched in the browser as i am writing the tests for testing..

Comment: you can do this with hasData

Answer (score 2):

You can't go back using Robotium, once you call an Activity outside the application under test, Robotium loses control over it. Similar questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10653576/android-robotium-how-to-go-back-to-my-activity-under-test-after-clicking-launch) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9696449/how-to-handle-external-application-activity-in-android-using-robotium).

One thing you can do is check if your Activity has lost focus using solo.hasWindowFocus() but this method can be tricky because if your Activity has a Dialog (or another Activity) on top, this method will return false even if you still in your AuT.